# Trying to push Data into JS function within WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Objective: 
I would like to take a JSON String and pass it into JavaScript function that is in an Android WebView.

What I am doing:
I need to get data out of an android SQLite database, turn it into JSON, pass it into the browser, and use a chart to display the data. I have accomplished all of this, except I cannot figure out how to pass the JSON into the JavaScript function/ into the browser.

So here I have a js function in my html header:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function returnData(json) {
                 //Do something in here with the JSON String
            }
        </script>
```

And then in my Java I have the javascript interface that I will cause the JS "returnData" function to be executed.

```
final class DemoJavaScriptInterface {
        DemoJavaScriptInterface() {
        }

        public void clickOnAndroid() {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    json = "[{ country: \\\"USA\\\", visits: 4252 },{ country: \\\"China\\\", visits: 1882 },{ country: \\\"Japan\\\", visits: 1809 }]";
                    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:returnData("+json+")");

                }
            });
        }
}
```

Now if I JUST want to execute the "returnData" function it gets executed just fine. (Below works)

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:returnData()");
```

But if I try and push a string into the function (like below), it just 'fails'... unfortunately I don't have much experience with JS, and so I have no idea why the JS function never gets called.

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:returnData("+json+")");
```

I am looking for ANY way to push data into a java script function, or somewhere in the DOM I can store the data (i guess) where the JS function could get the data from.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to add single quotes around the JSON string.

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:returnData('"+json+"')");
```

Comment: Amazing solution !